# Rails 4.2.11, User.find_by(name: 'name', email: 'email') returning array, not instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In Rails 4.2.11,

```
User.find_by(name: 'name', email: 'email')
```

is returning an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (containing array of one User instance) instead of one instance of User.

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, name: "Tester Test", email: "stester@xxx.xxx", created_at: "2021-04-27 14:08:49", updated_at: "2021-04-27 14:08:49">]>

This is happening in the context of a failing cucumber test where I create an authorization record and a user record.  The authorization record is found, but the user record comes back only as a Relation no matter what I do.  Tried .first, .take, several other ways to retrieve the instance.
```

This is identical to the output of `User.where`, not `User.find_by`.  Any idea why this is happening???

Answer (score 0):

And if you add '.first' like:
`User.find_by(name: 'name', email: 'email').first`
works for you?

Comment: I've tried a number of things, including adding .first (which was probably the 'first' thing I thought of) and .take, and some other constructs.  Returns EXACTLY the same result.  I've used find-by before to get one instance of something.  Can't figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working now, after I stopped running the test for about 10 minutes.  My only explanation is that there sometimes seems to be a discrepancy between my current code and what my ide terminal thinks it sees when my internet is glitchy.

I had originally used a `where` just to get an idea if it was working properly (to show myself that it was only going to return one valid record).  Then I modified it to be `find_by` (what I actually wanted), but it kept on returning results as if the `where` was still there.  Then, bingo, it started to behave as expected. ???

My only explanation is these intermittent outages are affecting the internet connection to my ide.